# How to add JavaScript if the URL has a certain word?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add the the following jQuery to the following pages only.

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/check-8.asp 

http://www.mywebsite.com/edit-8.asp

http://www.mywebsite.com/cart-8.asp
```

So this means I want to add it where URL string contains either `check-8`, `cart-8` or `edit-8`.

What is the best way with jQuery or JavaScript?

```
var text = $('#system td.td-main').html();

if (text != null)
{
  var newtext = text.replace("Pris","<div id=\"pricebox\">Pris").replace("mva\)","mva\)</div>");
  $('#system td.td-main').html(newtext);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if(location.pathname.indexOf('check-8') > 0 || location.pathname.indexOf('cart-8') > 0 || location.pathname.indexOf('edit-8') > 0){
//your code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a pure JavaScript solution, use the `window.location` property:

```
if (window.location.href.match(/(check|cart|edit)-8/).length > 0) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

You can use the *string.match* method to check if it matches a Regex. You can also factor it out if you need to know which one it is:

```
var matches = window.location.href.match(/(check|cart|edit)-8/);
if (matches.length > 0) {
    var action = matches[1]; // will be check, cart or edit
}
```

Comment: what should I put for /a_regex/ part?

Comment: I'm *guessing* what I have now should work, but I've not tested it.

Comment: Thanks. I found out that I don't want to add my jquery if it has cart-8 and check-8. But if it has art-8, then I want to add my jquery. What do you suggest in this case?

Comment: check out my code above. just modify the strings in the brackets.

Comment: @shin: You've already decided on a solution, but you'd just remove the 'c' from cart. Regexes can be a powerful tool - I only know the basics, but they make lots of string-handling much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use the following:

```
function testForCheckEditCart() {
  var patt = /(check|edit|cart)-8/i;
  return patt.test(location.href);
}
```